# PHP Yii: Database connect in runtime

Tags: php, yii, runtime, components

I would like to connect to a second database with Yii at runtime. The database name would come from a database table after the user to login.

I saw in a tutorial I should do this:

```
$db2 = Yii::createComponent(array(
    'class' => 'EMongoClient',
    'server' => 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017',
    'db' => $emp['database']
));

Yii::app()->setComponent('db2',$db2);
```

But in my controler when I access `Yii::app()->db2` get the error:

Property "CWebApplication.db2" is not defined

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
Yii::app()->mongodb->setActive(false);
Yii::app()->mongodb->setServer('mongodb://localhost:27017');
Yii::app()->mongodb->setDb('db1');
Yii::app()->mongodb->setActive(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

UPDATED: Try, instead instance, pass configurations:

> ```
> Yii::app()->setComponent( 'db2', array(
>                                       'class' => 'EMongoClient',
>                                       'server' => 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017',
>                                       'db' => $emp['database']
>                                   )
> );
> ```

Or, you may create special index on `params` in configurations, such as:

> ```
>   ...
>   'params' => array(
>          'db2' => null,
>      ),
> ```

And the use `Yii::app()->params['db2'] = $db2`

Comment: when I try to do this, I get the following error: `Missing argument 2 for CModule::setComponent()`

Comment: My problem is not with the creation of the component. Soon after creating if I access `Yii::app()->db2` its works, but when I try to access via another model or controller I get the error

Comment: Ok, try Yii::app()->setComponents( array('db2'=>$db2)); (with "s"). Or try Yii::app()->setComponent('db2', <array of configurations>)

Comment: Interesting. Another thought: reserv name db2 in main configuration and try to change it instanse. If not working, than you may create special key in 'params' and change it... try please

Comment: when i try to access `Yii::app()->params['db2']` its returns null.. I am trying to change the parameters inside a module, you know if yii have any restrictions in this regard?

Comment: As I understand, in module Yii::app()-> it is local module's enviroment. So, inside the module you can create component by ->setComponent('db2',... - it creates component db2 in the module. Then, I think, you can access to it from main app using Yii::app()->getModule($moduleName)->db2. Try it!

Answer (score 0):

From this comment:

> My problem is not with the creation of the component. Soon after
>   creating if I access Yii::app()->db2 its works, but when I try to
>   access via another model or controller I get the error

I think you are setting this component only once somewhere, and then making subsequent requests to different controllers.

You need to put the code, somewhere it is being called EVERYTIME, on every Request. thats how PHP works, there is no "global application state"

by default Yii comes with `protected/components/controller.php` has base controller for the rest of the app.

my suggestion would be to put your code on the `init()` method of that controller, so that it *always* gets called.

You mentioned the database name comes from a table once the user logs in, so you need to save that value in the session, in other to be able to access it in the other requests:

```
<?php

// After login in
Yii::app()->user->setState('db_name', $db_name);

// in protected/components/controller.php
public function init()
{
    if (!Yii::app()->user->isGuest) {
        $db2 = Yii::createComponent(array(
            'class' => 'EMongoClient',
            'server' => 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017',
            'db' => Yii::app()->user->getState('db_name')
        ));

        Yii::app()->setComponent('db2',$db2);
    }
}
```

Hope it helps, I am assuming many things here :)