# is it possible to "refresh" connection to db in runtime?

Tags: php, database, activerecord, yii

Here is my problem. I have a `yii` `web project` with a connection to a certain `db` that is defined in `main.php` like that:

```
'db'=>array(
'pdoClass' => 'NestedPDO',  
'connectionString' =>'sqlite:/var/www/my_project/protected/data/runtime/myDb.db',  
'class'            => 'CDbConnection',
'schemaCachingDuration' => 100,  
),
```

In one of the `php` scripts I run a command that copy a new `database` instead of the old one.
The problem is that in the script I don't notice the change.
For example, If in the databsae "myDb" there is a `table` named Table_1 that contains 4 records and in the new "myDb" that table contains 8 records, In my `php` script after I will run the command that changes "myDb" I will still see that "Table_1" has 4 records.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19428597/php-yii-database-connect-in-runtime

Answer (score 0):

Yii can be configured to run multiple DB's if thats what you are looking for 
something like this

```
...
'components' => array(
   'db'=>array(
      'pdoClass' => 'NestedPDO',  
      'connectionString' =>'sqlite:/var/www/my_project/protected/data/runtime/myDb.db',  
      'class'            => 'CDbConnection',
      'schemaCachingDuration' => 100,  
     ),
   'dbNew' => array(
       'pdoClass' => 'NestedPDO',  
       'connectionString' =>'sqlite:/var/www/my_project/protected/data/runtime/myDb_new.db',  
        'schemaCachingDuration' => 100,  
        'class'            => 'CDbConnection'          // DO NOT FORGET THIS!
    ),
    ...
```

Once this is defined, the second database is referred to as `Yii::app()->dbNew` rather than `Yii::app()->db`, the first is also available for your regular operations of course

Comment: If I understood you're solution right than it's not what I need. I don't need `yii`, in this case, to run another database. Just be updated that the original one was changed. The database remains in the same location, and I want to perform actions on it the same way using the same `models` that I already have.

Comment: You will have to manage only your query caching configurations, any application framework will expect the database to change all the time, if your query is not cached or cached incorrectly old data may be reflected, otherwise you will need no further changes. Note this is assuming the schema does not change. Yii Models(activeRecord) expects your schema to be as declared, changes to schema needs to be managed by migrations